# Regex replace, add a character if group exists

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to add a character if a group exists?

```
preg_replace('/(\()?\/:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\))?/', '\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'm/:x(/:s)');
```

Now, if group 1 or 2 exists (doesn't really matter) I'd like to add a "?" at the end of the string. Is it possible to do in a single regex?

Edit: Examples

`/:x` becomes `\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

BUT

`(/:x)` should become `\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` (with a question mark)

I want to know if I can achieve this with a SINGLE regexp.

Comment: what r u trying to achieve put an example.

Comment: In the replacement I want to add a "?" on the end if optional group 1 or 2 exists, the content of these groups is ( or )

Comment: Please, write an example string in your post and the result string you want to obtain. Actually your question is totally unclear and will be closed (or/and downvoted) without you obtain an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with:

```
$regexCallback = function($r) {
    return '\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)' . (isset($r[1]) ? "?" : "");
};
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('/(\()?\/:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\))?/', $regexCallback, $t));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have another way with only `preg_replace` since you can give an array for the pattern and the replacement param:

```
$patrep =  array ('~\(/:[a-z0-9]+\)~i' => '\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?',
                  '~/:[a-z0-9]+~i'     => '\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)');

$result = preg_replace(array_keys($patrep), $patrep, $str);
```

With this way, the original string is processed twice. However, it may be faster than using `preg_replace_callback` depending of how the original string looks like (size, nb of occurencies).